# Join table2 using xml in table1 - and return all entries from table2 as coalesced string

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an xml column, `geographyIdXml`, in table `table1`.

The xml in that column looks like this:

```
<args>
    <arg val="1" />
    <arg val="2" />
    miss a few..
    <arg val="99" />
    <arg val="100" />
</args>
```

The attribute `val` in each `<arg/>` tag refers to the id column of rows in the `geographies`  table.

I want to return a few columns from table1 and the geography names that relate back to the geographyIdXml field -- in a single row AND in a single column.

For example, if these are the columns returned:

```
id, name, geographies
```

the data will look like:

```
1, 'My spectacular campaign', 'New York, Paris, Peckham'
```

I've tried all afternoon to get this working.

Tried

```
cross apply geographyIdXml.nodes('args/arg') as ids(id)
inner join core..tbl_geography g on g.id = ids.id.value('@val','int')
```

but that just returns one row per entry in the xml

Tried the above and coalescing, but I couldn't get it to work.

If anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears. Thanks.

------ UPDATE - SQL EXAMPLE ---------

```
select r.*, coalesce(g.name + ', ','') as name
from campaignRun r
cross apply geographyIdXml.nodes('args/arg') as ids(id)
inner join geographies g on g.id = ids.id.value('@val','int')
where r.id = 1
```

I get ten rows returned - one for each node in the geographyIdXml field - which is wrong.

What I want is one row with a coalesced field of all geographies but somehow, I need to join my `geographies` table to my `campaignRun` table using the xml in the `geographyIdXml` field.

Thanks for any help you can offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started another answer to do the actual SQL.

Using the following setup stuff:

```
create table campaignrun (ID int, name varchar(50), geographyIDXml xml)

insert campaignrun
select 1, 'My Spectacular Campaign', '<args>
    <arg val="1" />
    <arg val="2" />
    <arg val="3" />
   </args>
'

create table geographies (ID int, name varchar(50))

insert geographies 
select 1, 'New York'
union select 2, 'Paris'
union select 3, 'Peckham'
```

This script:

```
select 
    r.ID, 
    r.Name,
    Geographies = STUFF(
        (SELECT ', ' + name 
        FROM 
            geographyIdXml.nodes('args/arg') as ids(id)
            join geographies g on g.id = ids.id.value('@val','int')
        FOR XML PATH (''))
        ,1,2,'')
from campaignRun r

where r.id = 1
```

Returns:

```
ID    Name                        Geographies
1     My Spectacular Campaign     New York, Paris, Peckham
```

The `FOR XML` bit is a cheat way of concatenating strings together. The `STUFF` is an easy way to remove the first two chars (ie ", ") from the beginning of the string.

Comment: no worries, glad to be of service (guvnor) - I like the "only fools" reference in the question

Answer (score 1):

So what you're trying to do is join all the geography names into a single name (concatenate them together). If so this recent SO question should give some ideas:

[Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: thanks for the link but i need the coalesce to work with some kind of joining of tables using an xml column

Comment: Please can you post the full SQL that you've got (that produces separate rows), then I can update it.

Comment: posted my horrendous sql now!